# Start LED blink at certain millis() value

Tags: millis

I was looking at the [blink without delay sketch](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BlinkWithoutDelay) and I was trying to modify it so the LED would start blinking after 1000 ms. I changed the `previousMillis` variable to 1000, but the program didn't change. In fact, it doesn't seem to change for any value of `previousMillis`. I thought that this would change the if statement:

`if (currentMillis - previousMillis >= interval)`

because 2000ms would have to pass for `currentMillis - previousMillis` to be equal to 1000ms (`interval`). What am I missing?

Comment: If you initialize `previousMillis` to 1000 then, initially, `currentMillis - previousMillis` is −1000. But you are dealing with _unsigned_ numbers, which cannot be negative, so the subtraction wraps around and you get 2^32−1000 = 4294966296.

Comment: Thanks, I removed the `unsigned` from both variables and it works now. However, is there any downside to this? And any better solutions?

Comment: “_is there any downside to [removing `unsigned`]?_” Yes. `millis()` will eventually overflow. Unsigned overflow is well behaved, whereas signed overflow is undefined behavior in C and C++. “_any better solutions?_” You can set an initial `interval` and change it later.